# Prove that $\int_0^\pi xa^{\sin x}dx\cdot\int_0^\pi a^{-\sin x}dx\geq\frac{\pi^3}{2}$ for $a > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Prove that
> $$\int_0^\pi xa^{\sin x}dx\cdot\int_0^\pi a^{-\sin x}dx\geq\frac{\pi^3}{2} , \quad a\gt 0 .$$

I know that put $a=1$ will get a equation, and I also tried Schwarz's inequation but didn't get a perfect lower bound.

I also considered multivariable calculus but didn't work that out either. So if you have various methods please point them out, this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\int_0^\pi x a^{\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x = 
\int_0^{\pi/2} x a^{\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi x a^{\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x = 
\pi \int_0^{\pi/2} a^{\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x$$
and
$$\int_0^\pi a^{-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x = \int_0^{\pi/2} a^{-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi a^{-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} a^{-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x.$$
(*Note*: For $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}$, use the substitution $x \to \pi - x$.)

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality for integrals, we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} a^{\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x \cdot \int_0^{\pi/2} a^{-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d} x
\ge \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{a^{\sin x}}\cdot \sqrt{a^{-\sin x}} \,\mathrm{d} x\right)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

We are done.

Comment: Sorry I only know there's a [Integral Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality) . But here the monotonicity condition is not satisfied and the direction of the inequality is opposite. Can you put it more clearly please?

Comment: @dmp How about Cauchy inequality for integrals?

Comment: @dmp I just found it is a typo for Chebyshev (I did not found it in the past). I mean Cauchy.